# Can I make a Julia package containing multiple modules that can be independently imported?

Tags: package, julia

One of the projects I'm collaborating on has four different modules (`Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`, and `Plotting`) and I've been tasked with combining them into a package. It is simple enough in Julia to make a new package:

```
julia> Pkg.generate("MyPackage", "MIT")
```

I copied my modules into the `~/.julia/v0.3/MyPackage/src/` and added include statements to `MyPackage.jl`. It looks something like this:

```
module MyPackage

include("foo.jl")
include("bar.jl")
include("baz.jl")
include("plotting.jl")

end
```

Each included file contains the corresponding module.

My main problem with this is `Plotting` takes *forever* to import and it's not needed very often when  we're using the rest of `MyPackage`. I'd really like to be able to do something like `using MyPackage.Foo` to just get `Foo` (and particularly to exclude the `Plotting` and its slow import time). I've tried a couple different approaches for how I structure things, including having sub-modules explicitly defined inside `MyPackage.jl` instead of in each file individually, but no matter what I try, I always get the loading lag from `Plotting`.

Is it possible build a package so you can independently load modules from it? and if so, how?

Note: I'm new to Julia and newer still to building packages. Sorry if any of my semantics are wrong or anything is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Requires.jl](https://github.com/one-more-minute/Requires.jl):

`Requires is a Julia package that will magically make loading packages faster, maybe. It supports specifying glue code in packages which will load automatically when a another package is loaded, so that explicit dependencies (and long load times) can be avoided.`

Comment: For anyone interested in more detail, `@lazymod` is a macro in `Requires.jl` that delays the import of a module until it is actually used, however, it also changes the syntax for calling the module. Though it doesn't feel like the most elegant solution, it certainly is handy for speeding up my imports until I actually need to plot. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that in the recent version of `Requires.jl`, the `@lazymod` feature has been removed...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible build a package so you can independently load modules from it? and if so, how?

Following the advice of this comment has worked for me:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/multiple-modules-in-single-package/5615/7?u=nhdaly

You can change the top-level package-named Module to simply just expose the other four Modules as follows:

```
# <julia_home>/MyPackage/src/MyPackage.jl
module MyPackage
push!(LOAD_PATH, @__DIR__) # expose all other modules defined in this directory.
end
```

Then to import the other modules, say `Bar`, the user code would do:

```
# code.jl
using MyPackage; using Foo;
...
```

But it's worth noting that, then, `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` and `Plotting` are all also treated as top-level modules, so you'll want to make their names unique so they don't conflict with other Packages/Modules. (ie somethig like `MyPackageFoo`, not `Foo`.)